# Ubuntu server: weird terminal

Tags: server

One of the ubuntu 10.10 servers present a weird terminal upon logon. It isn't bash. Even backspace does a weird thing. I have to manually enter bash to get my good old bash shell back. The server was installed from the stock CD and doesn't have any GUI.

I am curious what kind of shell is that and how do I make bash a default shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2009/03/changing-default-shell-in-ubuntu.html) will give you instructions on how to change the shell, there is a chsh command as far as I remember that should help you do it, but there are several other ways as well.